Healenium-self healing is not working with robotframework
i am using healenium with robotframework in this auto healing is not working i have to toggling locators  manually in reports then only its working fine for me it should be auto enabled by default but for me its disabled
it should be auto enabled by default but for me its disabled
i tried with SELF_HEALING_AUTO_ENABLED=true its also not working
start_healenium.sh
this is the file for start the healenium server
`# Requirements hlm_backend
HLM_POSTGRES_DB=healenium
HLM_POSTGRES_SCHEMA=healenium
HLM_POSTGRES_USER=healenium_user
HLM_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=YDk2nmNs4s9aCP6K
HLM_COLLECT_METRICS=true
HLM_SERVER_PORT=7878
HLM_LOG_LEVEL=info
HLM_FIND_ELEMENTS_AUTO_HEALING=true

# Requirements hlm_proxy
RECOVERY_TRIES=1
SCORE_CAP=.6
HEAL_ENABLED=true
SELENIUM_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4444
APPIUM_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
HEALENIUM_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:7878
HEALENIUM_SERVICE=http://localhost:7878
IMITATE_SERVICE=http://localhost:8000

